# Best approach for designing a Java class?

Tags: java, class

I hope I am asking the right question. This is just out of my curiosity and since I am not an experienced developer, I just to wanted to hear from you guys that what is the good approach while designing a class. Is there any standard approach or either one can be implemented? I just to want to know what is the conventional way of creating a class or what is your way?

Option 1:

```
public class Student{
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Student(String name, String address){
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void addStudent(){
        //add name and address to database.
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
public class Student{

    public void addStudent(String name, String address){
        //add name and address to database.
    }

    public void addAllStudent(List Student){
        //loop and add each student to database
    }
}
```

Method call:

```
//option 1:
Student s = new Student("abc","xyz");
s.addStudent();
//for list,
for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    Student s = new Student(list[i].name, list[i].address);
    s.addStudent();
}

//option 2:
Student s = new Student();
s.addStudent("abc","xyz");
s.addAllStudent(list);
```

Comment: it depends to what are you trying to do with class.

Comment: There is no 'best approach'. You should get out of the habit now of thinking there are silver bullets in this business. The basic fallacy was pointed out by Fred Brooks fifty years ago, in a book called, oddly enough, *No silver bullet.* There is just work.

Comment: neither, student should not have a method `addStudent`.

Comment: As with many things in software development there is no standard approach but there are a couple of best practices and principles that help in designing classes. Use those along with your knowledge of the business domain you're working in to create an architecture (that's what you are doing). One of the principles that comes to my mind when seeing your code is the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), i.e. a class should have only 1 responsibility (your's could be seen has having 2: representing a student and accessing the database).

Comment: as mentioned @user902383, `Student` shouldn't keep a list of other `Student`s

Comment: You shall keep Student separately and Group of Student separately. Group can easily be implemented using java collection

Comment: Its depends .. As per industry standard I would always prefer to use getter and setter for getting and setting data . Its good approach if you use no argument constructor. It is usefull when even you use constructor with parameres

Comment: @AndrewTobilko, consider, list of student is an arraylist, and Student is DAO class.

Comment: @Gokul, using getter and setter on for option 1??

Comment: @Thomas, thankyou for the information. It seems more clear now.

Comment: @RaKa, such list shouldn't be inside the `Student`

Comment: yes ... hope it wll help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Well... first things first... there is a difference between the a `Student`and a `List<Student>`

Normally you would create a class `Student`

```
public class Student{
  private String name;
  private String address;

  public Student(String name, String address){
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
  }

  // and some getter
}
```

and somewhere else in your code you can use a java List (not in your Student-Class)

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
Student peter = new Student("Peter", "somewhere");
Student frank = new Student("Frank", "somewhere else");
students.add(peter);
students.add(frank);
```

This Code snipped could be in your `SubscribeStudentToCourseService` or so...

What you want to do is - SingleResponsibility:

Create a class which is responsible for only one thing:

- a StudentClass which represents the student as a java model
- a course which represents a course (perhaps with a `List<Student>` field for the students who visit the course
- perhaps you write a Service To subscribe Students to a course

Comment: Now, its being more clearer. Thank you for "SingleResponsibility" tip.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is not good, since both methods dont really have anything to do with the Student object they belong to. You could make those two methods static. Option 1 is the "right" way for a `Student` class, but the method `addStudent()` is wrong. You can have a method in your database and call `database.addStudent(objStudent)`.
You could also change the `addStudent` method in your `Student` class to `addToDatabase(Database db)` or even

```
static void addToDatabase(Student student, Database db)
```

In the specific case of a List as Database, there is no need for a custom add method at all, because List allready has the add method.

In the most simple case it all boils down to:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
students.add(new Student("Max", "###"));
```

If you think the second line is too complicated, you can create a static method in Student:

```
public static void addStudent(String name, String address, List<Student> students)
{
    students.add(new Student(name, address);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
Student.addStudent("Max", "###", students);
```

From personal preference i would not do the latter. It bugs me a little that its not transparent enough in terms of what the method actually does with the list. There is nothing wrong with simply using the add method of the list in the first case.

Comment: Thank you Mario Dekena. So, basically, dont let your model class to store date instead use some controller which does all the work; List in your case, which contain methods to save to database and takes student as parameter. Here, student is more like simple object with attributes, getter and setter and some validation on data. Correct me If i am wrong.

Comment: @RaKa Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see there are a lot of opinions on this question, so I go and add another one ;)

Someone commented that there is no "silver bullet" to use when creating new instances of a class. That pretty much hits the bull's eye. There are many ways, straight forward via a constructor, via static methods or wrapped in Factories. And there are even very good arguments to create an instance via `reflections`.

The same is true for how to save your students to the database. There are many patterns that may be valid. Just make sure you understand how that pattern works and what are the benefits and disadvantages. And just as important, use it consequently throughout your code.

Regarding your code, your option 2 does not make sense if you change to a  modeling perspective. Adding students to a student? Unless you don't want to create a human pile of students, you better add students to a course, a class, a school...

Comment: Thank you for your information Matt.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the same class to provide a template for a Student, and also to store Students.

Do you really need to store students in the same class? It will lead to some confusing design, where you've got a Student class storing other Student classes which actually represent a student.

Perhaps the functionality for adding a student could be in a separate class, such as a School? Or you just create a generic List of Students wherever you need them. So the addStudent functions could possibly be removed from the class and stored elsewhere.

Comment: Every answers here is helping me a lot and point to same suggestion. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

1. Create a `Student` bean

   ```
   public class Student {
       private String name;
       private String address;

       public Student(String name, String address) {
           this.name = name;
           this.address = address;
       }

       // generate the getters and setters
   }
   ```
2. Create the `DAO` class

   ```
   public class StudentDaoIml {
       public void addStudent(Student student) {
           // do the add student job here
       }

       public void addAll(List<Student> students) {
           // the code goes here
       }

       public void deleteStudent(Student student) {

       }

       ...
   }
   ```
3. At the end you can use it like this:

   ```
   StudentDaoIml stDao = new StudentDaoIml();
   for(int i=0;i<someValue; i++){
       Student s = new Student(list[i].name, list[i].address);
       stDao.addStudent(s);
   }
   ```

Comment: Yeah... that is what I am doing so far. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! If the answer helped you, then accept the answer, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Here's a good way and some explanation in comments.

```
public class Student{
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Student(String name, String address){
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void save(){
        //save this instance to database.
    }
    public static void saveAll(List<Student> students){
        //Either iterate and call save
        // or do better batch insert for better performance
    }
}
```

As far as naming a method is concerned, class methods are named in terms of their behaviour. Think of it like telling an instance of student to 'go and *save* yourself to DB'. There could be one more method like 'go and *update* yourself in DB'.

When you are dealing with a list, the list itself should not be part of the Student class. Keep the list somewhere else. However, the Student class could have a static method which takes a list of students and saves them in one shot.

For example, the students could be in a class in a school. Then

```
Student.saveAll(class5A.getStudents());
```

Create a few and save them:

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    Student s = new Student("Student" + i, "Student address " + i);
    students.add(s);
}

Student.saveAll(students);
```

Going one step further, Student class should probably not deal with saving students in bulk. So, let's relieve it of that duty and let the BatchOfClass take care of that.

```
public class Student{
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Student(String name, String address){
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void save(){
        //save this instance to database.
    }
}

public class BatchOfClass{ //Students who are in grade 6 in 2016
    private String className;
    private String batchName;
    private List<Student> students;

    public BatchOfClass(...){
    }

    public void save(boolean saveStudents){
        //save this instance to database.
        //This would also save the students to DB if saveStudents==true
    }
}
```

Comment: `Here's a good way` - I'd say the OP would want some explanation on _why_ you consider that a good way.

Comment: @Teddy why are you adding DAO components in a pojo kind of class??

Comment: it isn't a good way, `Student` shouldn't take care of other `Student`s (as you showed with `saveAll`)

Comment: @Imram, regarding the Active Record pattern it would not be false if the Student entity is in charge of saving itself. Even finding Students could be realized via a static implementation. If this is "good way" as stated is another story.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko There are various levels of 'better'. I agree with you and I'm not a fan of static methods either. But, would you suggest I stray to a totally different topic like ORM for this simple use case?

Comment: @Thomas Added some comments.

Comment: @Teddy, no, I would unmark `addStudents` as `static` and put it in a class like `Group` or `Department`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Sure.. makes sense.